# Quais as diferenças entre as figuras de linguagem: antítese, metonímia, metáfora, comparação e sinestesia

Tags: linguagem, figuras-de-linguagem

Acho este assunto sobre "figuras de linguagem" um tanto confuso.

Quais as diferenças entre as figuras de linguagem: antítese, metonímia, metáfora, comparação e sinestesia.

Quais seriam os melhores exemplos para diferencia-las?

Comment: São figuras tão distintas que fica até difícil comparar.

Comment: Antítese, metonímia e sinestesia⸮ Essas não têm _nada_ a ver com as outras; as únicas vagamente semelhantes são a comparação e a metáfora.

Comment: @someonewithpc ⸮? :)

Comment: @bfavaretto Marca uma pergunta retórica explicitamente https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irony_punctuation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### [FIGURAS DE LINGUAGEM](http://rachacuca.com.br/educacao/portugues/figuras-de-linguagem/)

São recursos de expressão, utilizados para ampliar o significado de um texto ou suprir a falta de termos adequados em uma frase.

As mais comuns são: **antítese**, **metonímia**, **metáfora**, **comparação**,   **sinestesia**, paradoxo, personificação (ou prosopopeia), hipérbole, eufemismo, ironia, elipse, zeugma, pleonasmo, polissíndeto, assíndeto, onomatopeia, anáfora, , gradação e aliteração.

---

### [Antítese](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ant%C3%ADtese)

A antítese consiste no uso de palavras, expressões ou ideias que se opõem.
Exemplo:

> **Soneto da Separação**
>
> De **repente do riso fez-se o pranto** 
>   Silencioso e branco como a bruma 
>   E das **bocas unidas fez-se a espuma** 
>   E das mãos espalmadas fez-se o espanto
>
> *Vinícius de Moraes*

### [Metonímia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meton%C3%ADmia)

É a substituição de uma palavra por outra sendo que, entre ambas, há uma proximidade de sentidos, uma relação de implicação.
 Exemplos:

> - Não leu **Machado de Assis**.
> - Não leu **a obra** de Machado de Assis.

Vemos no exemplo que a obra de Machado de Assis foi substituída só pelo nome do autor. A metonímia consiste nessa substituição de palavras, dando o mesmo sentido a uma frase. A seguir, outro exemplo que reforça essa substituição:

> - A **cozinha** italiana é maravilhosa!
> - A **comida** italiana é ótima.

### [Metáfora](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Met%C3%A1fora)

A metáfora é um tipo de comparação, mas sem os termos comparativos (*tal como, como, são como, tanto quanto, etc*). Na metáfora, a comparação entre dois elementos está implícita, trazendo uma relação de semelhança entre eles.
 Exemplo:

> Tempo é dinheiro.

Percebemos neste exemplo a relação implícita, onde o tempo é tão valoroso quanto o dinheiro, por isso ele é colocado como semelhante à moeda.

### [Comparação](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compara%C3%A7%C3%A3o)

A comparação consiste na aproximação entre dois objetos por meio de uma característica semelhante entre eles, dando a um as características do outro. Difere da metáfora porque possui, obrigatoriamente, termos comparativos. Em suma, é uma comparação explícita. 
Exemplo:

> Tempo é **como** dinheiro.

Neste exemplo vemos o principal definidor de uma comparação: a palavra como traz explicitamente a ideia de que o tempo é valoroso **como** o dinheiro.

### [Sinestesia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinestesia)

A sinestesia traz textos que expressam as sensações humanas, com o cruzamento de palavras referentes aos cinco sentidos. 
Exemplo:

> **Recordação**
>
> Agora, o **cheiro áspero** das flores 
>  
>   leva-me os olhos por dentro de suas pétalas
>
> *Cecília Meireles*

Aqui, vamos uma característica do olfato (cheiro) misturada com outra do tato (áspero).

### [Paradoxo](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paradoxo)

Paradoxo é a presença de elementos que se anulam numa frase, trazendo à tona uma situação que foge da lógica. 
Exemplo:

> Amor é fogo que arde sem se ver; 
>  
>   É **ferida que dói e não se sente**; 
>  
>   É um **contentamento descontente**; 
>  
>   É **dor que desatina sem doer**;
>
> *Luís de Camões*

A situação do paradoxo aqui é clara: os elementos marcados se anulam, trazendo uma série de questionamentos. Como pode uma ferida, algo que causa dor física, não ser sentida? Como o contentamento, que causa felicidade, pode ser descontente? Como a dor pode não doer? Vemos claramente a fuga da lógica.

### [Personificação ou Prosopopeia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personifica%C3%A7%C3%A3o)

A personificação, também chamada prosopopeia, consiste na atribuição de características humanas, como sentimentos, linguagem humana e ações do homem, a coisas não-humanas.
 
Exemplo:

> **Congresso Internacional do Medo**
>
> Provisoriamente não cantaremos o amor, 
>  
>   que se refugiou mais abaixo dos subterrâneos. 
>  
>   Cantaremos o medo, que esteriliza os abraços, 
>  
>   não cantaremos o ódio, porque esse não existe, 
>   **existe apenas o medo, nosso pai e nosso companheiro**.
>
> *Carlos Drummond de Andrade*

Neste exemplo, o medo, uma sensação, é transformado em pai e companheiro, algo que só é atribuído a um ser humano.

### [Hipérbole](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hip%C3%A9rbole_(figura_de_estilo))

Esta figura de linguagem consiste no emprego de palavras que expressam uma ideia de exagero de forma intencional. 
Exemplo:

> Ela **chorou rios** de lágrimas.

Chorar rios remete a um choro contínuo, exagerado e o termo rios vem para enfatizar a ideia de que foi um choro intenso.

### [Eufemismo](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eufemismo)

O eufemismo ocorre quando utilizamos palavras ou expressões que atenuam e substituem outras que produzem um efeito desagradável e chocante. 
Exemplos:

> - **Faltei com a verdade** ao dizer que fui à igreja.
> - **Menti** ao dizer que fui à igreja.

A expressão e o impacto negativo que a palavra **menti** traz é "suavizado" ao dizer que "**faltei com a verdade**".

### [Ironia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ironia)

É a expressão de ideias com significado oposto ao que se realmente pensa ou acredita. Exemplo:

> Moça linda, bem tratada, 
>  
>   Três séculos de família, 
>  
>   Burra como uma porta: 
>  
>   **Um amor!**
>
> *Mário de Andrade*

O trecho é o exemplo claro de ironia: a moça é descrita como, bonita e bem tratada, tradicional, conservadora (é de família) e burra. O destaque em "um amor", apoiando-se na descrição da moça, mostra que ela, ao contrário de ser esse "amor de pessoa", é, na verdade, alguém sem atrativos, sem graça.

### [Elipse](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elipse_(figura_de_estilo))

Temos elipse quando, em um texto, alguns elementos são omitidos sem ocasionar a perda de sentido, uma vez que as palavras omitidas ficam subentendidas através do contexto. Exemplos:

> - Ela está passando mal! Depressa, um médico!
> - Ela está passando mal! Depressa, *chamem* um médico!

Na primeira frase temos a elipse ao vermos que a palavra *chamem* está escondida. Não é necessário colocá-la e não há perda de sentido, porque mesmo sem ela entendemos que é necessário chamar um médico depressa porque ela está passando mal.

### [Zeugma](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeugma)

É parecido com a elipse, no entanto, só podemos identificar desta forma esta figura de linguagem quando há omissão de algo que já foi expresso no texto. Sabemos que o termo foi omitido porque já foi apresentado. Exemplo:

> **Canção do Exílio**
>
> Nosso céu **tem** mais estrelas 
>   Nossas várzeas **tem** mais flores  
>   Nossos bosques **tem** mais vida 
>   **Nossa vida mais amores**
>
> *Gonçalves Dias*

Neste trecho vemos a omissão da palavra tem no último trecho. Não foi necessário o emprego dessa palavra para entender que a vida tem mais amores, pois já houve repetição da palavra nos outros versos.

### [Pleonasmo](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pleonasmo)

Repetição de uma ideia por meio de outras palavras. É utilizado como forma de ênfase e, além de ser figura de linguagem, é classificada como vício. A diferença entre a figura de linguagem e o vício de linguagem é simples: para ser figura de linguagem, o pleonasmo vem de forma intencional, para dar mais expressividade no texto, enquanto no vício vem como uma repetição não intencional e desnecessária. Exemplo:

> Quando hoje acordei, ainda fazia escuro 
>   (Embora a manhã já estivesse avançada). 
>   Chovia. 
>   **Chovia uma triste chuva** de resignação 
>   Como contraste e consolo ao calor tempestuoso da noite.
>
> *Manuel Bandeira*

A repetição proposital de Manuel Bandeira ao dizer que "chovia uma chuva" intensifica a ideia de que estava chovendo.

### [Polissíndeto](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poliss%C3%ADndeto)

Consiste na repetição de conjunções para garantir um texto mais expressivo. Exemplo:

> **O olhar para trás**
>
> **E** o olhar estaria ansioso esperando 
>   **E** a cabeça ao sabor da mágoa balançada
>   **E** o coração fugindo **e** o coração voltando
>   **E** os minutos passando **e** os minutos passando...
>
> *Vinícius de Moraes*

A conjunção e vem para caracterizar o polissíndeto, trazendo ações e sensações que ocorrem de forma contínua e rápida.

### [Assíndeto](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ass%C3%ADndeto)

O assíndeto ocorre quando há omissão das conjunções. Exemplo:

> **Morte no avião**
>
> Acordo para a morte. 
>   **Barbeio-me, visto-me, calço-me.**
>
> *Carlos Drummond de Andrade*

A conjunção geralmente é substituída por vírgula, como no exemplo.

### [Onomatopeia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Onomatopeia)

Temos onomatopeia quando há o uso de palavras que reproduzem os sons de seres vivos e objetos. É mais comum em história em quadrinhos.

[image]

### [Anáfora](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/An%C3%A1fora)

Consiste na repetição de palavras ou expressões com o objetivo de enfatizar uma ideia. Exemplo:

> **Elegia Desesperada**
>
> Tende piedade, Senhor, de todas as mulheres
>   **Que ninguém mais** merece tanto amor e amizade
>   **Que ninguém mais** deseja tanto poesia e sinceridade
>   **Que ninguém mais** precisa tanto de alegria e serenidade
>
> *Vinícius de Moraes

### [Gradação](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grada%C3%A7%C3%A3o)

Nesta figura as ideias aparecem de forma crescente ou decrescente dentro de um texto. Exemplo:

> **Meia noite em ponto em Xangai**
>
> A mulher **foi-se encolhendo**, agarrada aos braços da poltrona. 
>   **Cravou o olhar** esgazeado no retângulo negro do céu. 
>   **Encolheu-se mais ainda**, cruzando os braços. 
>   **Limpou as mãos** pegajosas no brocado da bata.
>   **Susteve a respiração**.
>
> *Lygia Fagundes Telles*

Aqui a gradação crescente vem trazendo uma ideia da sensação do medo que vai aumentando.

### [Aliteração](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alitera%C3%A7%C3%A3o)

Consiste na repetição de consoantes em uma sequência de palavras, trazendo um texto com um efeito sonoro. Confira um exemplo no trecho da música Chove Chuva de Jorge Ben Jor:

> **Ch**ove, **ch**uva, **ch**ove sem parar

Neste caso, o **ch** repetido vem para dar a sonoridade da chuva, além de dar ritmo à música de *Jorge Ben Jor*.

Answer (score 3):

> **Figuras de linguagem** são maneiras de tornar as mensagens que emitimos mais expressivas. São subdivididas em figuras de som, figuras
> de palavras, figuras de pensamento e figuras de construção.

---

**ANTÍTESE**

> É uma figura de pensamento, consiste na utilização de dois termos que
> contrastam entre si. Ocorre quando há uma aproximação de palavras ou
> expressões de sentidos opostos. O contraste que se estabelece serve,
> essencialmente, para dar uma ênfase aos conceitos envolvidos que não
> se conseguiria com a exposição isolada dos mesmos.

**Exemplos:**

- *O mito é o **nada** que é **tudo**.*
- *O corpo é **grande** e a alma é **pequena**.*
- *Quando um muro **separa**, uma ponte **une**.*
- ***Desceu** aos pântanos com os tapires; **subiu** aos Andes com os condores.*
- ***Felicidade** e **tristeza** tomaram conta de sua alma.*

---

**METONÍMIA**

> É uma figura de palavra, consiste em empregar um termo no lugar de outro, >havendo entre ambos estreita afinidade ou relação de sentido.

**Exemplos:**

- Autor pela obra: *Gosto de ler **Machado de Assis**. (= Gosto de ler a **obra literária de Machado de Assis**.)*
- Efeito pela causa: *Sócrates bebeu a **morte**. (= Sócrates tomou **veneno**.)*
- Continente pelo conteúdo: Bebeu o **cálice** todo. (= Bebeu todo o **líquido** que estava no cálice.)

---

**METÁFORA**

> Também é uma figura de palavra, consiste em utilizar uma palavra ou
> uma expressão em lugar de outra, sem que haja uma relação real, mas em
> virtude da circunstância de que o nosso espírito as associa e
> depreende entre elas certas semelhanças. É importante notar que a
> metáfora tem um caráter subjetivo e momentâneo; se a metáfora se
> cristalizar, deixará de ser metáfora e passará a ser catacrese (é o
> que ocorre, por exemplo, com "pé de alface", "perna da mesa", "braço
> da cadeira").
>
> **Obs.: toda metáfora é uma espécie de comparação implícita, em que o elemento comparativo não aparece.**

**Observe a gradação no processo metafórico abaixo:**

- *Seus olhos são como luzes brilhantes. (=Este exemplo mostra uma comparação evidente, através do emprego da palavra como.)*

**Observe agora:**

- *Seus olhos são luzes brilhantes. (=Nesse exemplo não há mais uma comparação (note a ausência da partícula comparativa), e sim um **símile**, ou seja, qualidade do que é semelhante.)*

**Por fim, no exemplo:**

- *As luzes brilhantes olhavam-me. (=Há substituição da palavra **olhos** por **luzes brilhantes**. Essa  é a verdadeira metáfora.)*

**Mais exemplos:**

- *Meu pensamento é um rio subterrâneo (=Nesse caso, a metáfora é possível na medida em que o poeta estabelece relações de semelhança entre um rio subterrâneo e seu pensamento [pode estar relacionando a fluidez, a profundidade, a inatingibilidade, etc.]*
- *Minha alma é uma estrada de terra que leva a lugar algum (=Uma estrada de terra que leva a lugar algum é, na frase acima, uma metáfora. Por trás do uso dessa expressão que indica uma alma rústica e abandonada [e angustiadamente inútil], há uma comparação subentendida: Minha alma é tão rústica, abandonada [e inútil] quanto uma estrada de terra que leva a lugar algum)*

---

**COMPARAÇÃO**

> Consiste na aproximação de dois termos entre os quais existe alguma relação de semelhança, como na metáfora. A comparação, porém, é feita por meio de um conectivo (com, como, parecia e etc.) e busca realçar determinada qualidade do meio termo (como, tal, qual, assim, quanto etc.)*

**Exemplos:**

- *O Amor queima como o fogo.*
- *O mar canta como um canário.*
- *A cidade, adormecida, parecia um cemitério sem fim.*

---

**SINESTESIA**

> Consiste em mesclar, numa mesma expressão, as sensações percebidas por
> diferentes órgãos do sentido.

**Exemplos:**

- Um **grito áspero** revelava tudo o que sentia. (grito = auditivo; áspero = tátil)
- No **silêncio negro** do seu quarto, aguardava os acontecimentos. (silêncio = auditivo; negro = visual)

---

Existem várias outras figuras de linguagem, mas essas são as que você citou.